# Specify italic font for PDFlaTeX

Tags: fonts

For my PDFlaTeX document I`d like to use roboto slab light for the main text and roboto in titles. I am having the following problems:

1. if I set roboto slab light as main font, then I do not know how to set roboto for titles only. I try to do that with \sffamily, but it does not work. What I get is a document written completely in roboto slab light (incl. titles)
2. roboto slab light is that it does not have italics - how to specify a different font (e.g. roboto) to be used with \textit and \emph{}?

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, english]{report}
\usepackage[rm, light]{roboto} %this makes roboto slab light the main document font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titling}
\titleformat*{\section}{\sffamily\Large} %with sffamily I try to set roboto regular as section title font

\begin{document}
\section{I need to be in roboto font}
I am normal text and need to be in roboto slab light font.
\textit{I am in italics and need a different font, e.g. roboto}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly load the font definition file, so you'll be able to add some declarations afterwards.

For the section titles, specify the `Roboto-LF` family.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[rm,light]{roboto}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\input{\encodingdefault RobotoSlab-TLF.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{l}{it}{
 <->ssub*Roboto-TLF/l/it
}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontfamily{Roboto-LF}\fontseries{m}\Large}

\begin{document}

\section{I need to be in roboto font}


I am normal text and need to be in roboto slab light font.
\textit{I am in italics and need a different font, e.g. roboto}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Error: Font family 'T1+RobotoSlab-TLF' unknown` - perhaps the substitution is going wrong?

Comment: @tdc I fixed it; since the answer, the name of the `.fd` file has changed.

Comment: Nice - working Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This requires a switch to LuaLaTeX, and might not work for every situation. But is is sufficiently related to the original question:

Using `fontspec` syntax, you can create a hybrid font family. The regular font can be one file, the bold can be from a different family, and the italic can be from a different family. You set it up by requesting the specific file names (Open Type preferred, TrueType second choice). Like this:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Note that \usepackage{roboto} is not used here.
% But you must the package installed, at least its TrueType fonts.
\setmainfont[ %
  ItalicFont=Roboto-LightItalic.ttf, % or whatever
  BoldFont=Roboto-Regular.ttf, % uses regular in place of bold
]{RobotoSlab-Light.ttf} % main font
%
\begin{document}
\section{\textbf{I need to be in roboto font}}
I am normal text and need to be in roboto slab light font.
\textit{I am in italics and need a different font, e.g. roboto}
\end{document}
```

I was not able to get it to work with the `\titleformat*` command, though.

You do not use packages `fontenc` or `inputenc`. In some cases (not all) you do not load the fonts via `\usepackage{font}`.
[image: roboto text]