# How to properly use different math alphabets in titles/table of contents?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, table-of-contents

I am using bold font series for the titles and light font series for the table of contents, using Roboto sans-serif font for these two puroposes (but I do *not* want to use Roboto for the rest). The trouble I am facing is that I would need to adapt the math font depending on whether it is in a title, or it is used in the ToC.

The MWE below shows that titles are ok, but the ToC is not ok since I am forcing the bold series for the math.
[image: ok]
[image: not_ok]

How would you proceed to get the desired result? (Ideally, I would like a solution which I could adapt also to headers with still another series of fonts...).

---

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc, titleps}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\MathSFB}{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{it}%b = bold
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\MathSFL}{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{it}%l = light

\titleformat{\chapter}{\usefont{T1}{Roboto-LF}{b}{n}}{Chapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{}{\usefont{T1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{n}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test $\MathSFB{a = b}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the optional argument of `\chapter`. See also: [How to make mathematics bold in headings](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_HeadingsBoldMath/) resp. [Wie Mathematik in Überschriften fett gesetzt werden kann](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_HeadingsBoldMath/)

Comment: Hope this will helps you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365930/specify-italic-font-for-pdflatex/365981#365981